# Do any characters in The Simpsons age over time?

Tags: the-simpsons

Do any non celebrity characters in The Simpsons get older over the course of the series? I know that most characters stay the same age but want to know if anyone bucks this trend.
I am asking about people in episodes set in the present, so flashbacks and flash forwards don't count.

I'm not counting characters who died and stayed dead.

I'm not counting celebrities as that is covered in this question: [Have any celebrity guests noticeably "aged" over the course of their appearances on The Simpsons?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112717/have-any-celebrity-guests-noticeably-aged-over-the-course-of-their-appearances)

Comment: I assume you're not counting characters who have had a birthday during the show?  I think that's happened a few times, but they didn't visibly change at all.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman As far as I'm aware they don't actually increase in age on their birthdays.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Nahasapeemapetilon octuplets age slightly from newborns to toddlers. In "Eight Misbehavin'" (S11E7), Manjula gives birth to the newborn octuplets. In subsequent appearances, the children are toddlers able to walk, so they must have aged by about a year or more. It's a small amount of aging, and they don't continue to get older as the series progresses, but we do see them grow beyond being newborns.

Comment: "It's a small amount of aging..." from 1 hour to 1 year for example is 875,900% older :-)

Answer (score 36):

Apu's nephew, [Jamshed "Jay" Nahasapeemapetilon](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Jay_Nahasapeemapetilon) went from toddler ([S4 E3](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Homer_the_Heretic)) to late teen ([S27 E12](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Much_Apu_About_Something)).

The wiki even states:

> Jamshed has aged the most out of all characters in The Simpsons, aging from a toddler to someone in his late teens.

Comment: So he aged at about half the rate of viewers' time.

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe the question asked for us to do the math but you are correct.

Comment: It was just an interesting fact. Most characters don't age at all, the octuplets aged a tiny bit according to the other answer, and he aged at about half speed. It's also interesting that this is the only family in town where aging happens at all. Is this related to "The problem with Apu" :)

Comment: I think somebody thought it was a duplicate of Nuclear Hoagie's answer, but Jay isn't one of the octuplets, he's Apu's nephew, not his son.

Answer (score 14):

Also Selma's adopted daughter [Ling Bouvier](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Ling_Bouvier).

She started as a newborn in [S16 E12](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Goo_Goo_Gai_Pan) and now is a toddler ([S24 E11](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Changing_of_the_Guardian))